# Font Awesome не отображается на главной, но отображается на других страницах

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте,

На всех страницах сайта подключен font-awesome.css

```
<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

При этом на главной странице иконки font-awesome не отображаются, а на остальных все ок.

В инструментах разработчика видно что на главной странице даже не совершается загрузка файлов шрифта браузером, хотя элементы font-awesome на странице есть. Например:

```
<div class="SmallMenuToggle col-xs-2 visible-xs">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Ниже скриншот корневой директории сайта.

[image: корневая директория]

Секция <head> корневой страницы (font-awesome *не работает*; без мета-тегов):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css">
<title>Главная</title>
<link href="/landing/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/landing/css/app.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="/assets/89c6b9b5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Секция <head> страницы входа (font-awesome *работает*; без мета-тегов):

```
<title>Вход</title>
<link href="/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/89c6b9b5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

В файле site.css указывается загрузка шрифта KB-Zero. Шрифт подгружается везде где нужно.

Comment: Попробуйте переместить подключение `font-awesome.css ` после `<title>Главная</title>`

Comment: ссылку на сайт можно?

Comment: Вроде ничего подозрительного. Может порядок подключения файлов? Или стандартная отмазка "почистить кеш"?

Comment: Уверены что с главной страницы есть доступ к font-awesom? Что нет никаких ошибок в консоле, например 404 при попытки загрузить `.css` или ошибок авторизации?

Comment: @Vartlok в консоли нет никаких ошибок. Будь проблемы с доступом, были бы ошибки, но тут даже нет попытки обратиться к файлам шрифта

Comment: @atom-22 А сама css-ка font-awesome.css на главной подгружается и если  в инструментах разработчика браузера выбрать элемент с иконкой awesome стили css-ки применяются/их видно?